# Retornar quantidade de células de acordo com parametro de um datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Preciso pegar as células duplicadas de uma determinada coluna, existe alguma função da linguagem que me retorne essas células duplicadas? Exemplo:

```
coluna-1  coluna-2
    1        87
    2        9
    3        12
    1        17
    2        28
```

teria que me retornar o `valor 1,2`  ou as linhas que estes valores se encontram da coluna-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `System.Linq;`

```
var ret = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["c1"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Exemplo completo:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("c1");
dt.Columns.Add("c2");

dt.Rows.Add(1, 87);
dt.Rows.Add(2, 9);
dt.Rows.Add(3, 12);
dt.Rows.Add(1, 17);
dt.Rows.Add(2, 28);

var ret = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["c1"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
var ret2 = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["c2"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

foreach (var value in ret)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Key);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Pode testar online:

http://rextester.com/OYHGL73505